# WxWidgets and STL Vector

Tags: c++, list, vector, wxwidgets

So, I am new to programing and I have this problem.

I have written a console app in which I can add objects to STL vector.

Some code:

Element.h (Objects of this class I store in Vector)

```
class Element
{
 private:
      string speaker_name;
      string color_membrane;
      string color_main;
      string size_main;
      string color_terminals; 
      string size_terminals;
  public:
      Element();
      ~Element();
     string Get_color_membrane();
     string Get_color_main();
     string Get_size_main();    
     string Get_color_terminals();
     string Get_size_terminals();
     string Get_speaker_name();

     void Set_color_membrane(string);
     void Set_color_main(string);
     void Set_size_main(string);
     void Set_color_terminals(string);

     void Set_size_terminals(string);
     void Set_speaker_name(string);
```

Doc.cpp  (class with vector)

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <vector>
  #include "Doc.h"
  using namespace std;
  vector <Element> MyElements;

  void Doc::Add_item(Element const& TempElement)
  {
      MyElements.push_back(TempElement);
  }
```

App.cpp

```
  Doc doc;
  Element TempElement;
  cout << "Add new Element" << endl;
            cout << "Input NAME of speaker" << endl;
            cin >> temp_string;
            TempElement.Set_speaker_name(temp_string);
            cout << "Input COLOR of membrane" << endl;
            cin >> temp_string;
            TempElement.Set_color_membrane(temp_string);
            cout << "Input COLOR of main body of speaker " << endl;
            cin >> temp_string;
            TempElement.Set_color_main(temp_string);
            cout << "Input stroke SIZE of membrane & main body" << endl;
            cin >> temp_string;
            TempElement.Set_size_main(temp_string);
            cout << "Input COLOR of terminals" << endl;
            cin >> temp_string;
            TempElement.Set_color_terminals(temp_string);
            cout << "Input stroke SIZE of terminals" << endl;
            cin >> temp_string;
            TempElement.Set_size_terminals(temp_string);
       doc.Add_item(TempElement);
```

The thing is: I am writing a window-based app in WxWidgets.

My project looks like this:

[image]

(It's just for testing purposes - it does nothing)

And, now I would like to create a method of making some sort of list of this objects from STL vector (where red arrow points),
It should look more or less like this:

[image]

and be able to communicate with STL vector

Thanks in advance for all your help.

~Thermoos

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  Try to narrow the scope of your question.

Comment: What would you like me to explain?

Comment: I would like to make a list (pic you can see in my post) of objects from STL vector

Answer (score 0):

The simplest control you can use to display your items is [wxListBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_box.html). There is also [wxEditableListBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_editable_list_box.html) which comes with the built-in buttons, but it doesn't look quite the same, check the editlbox sample showing it in action.

Comment: Do you have any more tips for me on how to connect wxListBox to stl vector? Any tutorial on wxListBox?

Comment: As with any wxWidgets control, look at how it is used in the samples. There is no magic connection between vectors and list boxes (or any other control), you can implement it but you would have to actually do it.